# App background script, accessing elements of opened window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I am working on a Chrome App, and I need the background script to access elements of an html window that it creates.

*Please do not answer that I can do it from other scripts launched by the created window, because this is not what I need.*

This is my background.js file:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
   chrome.app.window.create('window.html',
      {'outerBounds': {'width': 600, 'height': 500 }},
      function(myWin) {
          myWin.contentWindow.document.getElementById('areaId').value='New text!';
   }); 
});
```

and this is windows.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="areaId" name="areaId"  rows="4" cols="50">
      This is my text.
    </textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I launch the app, I get the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"

I also tried with `myWin.document.getElementById(...)`
and opening the window with var `myWin=window.open(...)`
but without success.

So my question is, how can I access elements of the newly created window from the background script?

Comment: `myWin.contentWindow.document` should be correct. You should edit your question with that and tell what isn't working and how it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks, this answers part of my doubts, although I still have an error. I edited my question as you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so what happens here is wrong timing.

The callback of `create` executes before the DOM structure of the page is constructed; therefore, `getElementById('areaId')` doesn't find anything *yet*.

You can try to hook into the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Alternatively, you can go the [recommended route](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#property-create-callback) and define some functions/variables in that callback that the code in the opened window can then use (docs recommend `onload`).

Comment: That's interesting, thank you for your answer. Indeed both solutions are suitable for my problem.